# Hot to disable a button when a TextField is editing (multiple buttons / TextFields in Grid)

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a `LazyVGrid` in which data is displayed in several columns and in which a field can also be edited via `TextField`.
I now want to disable a `Button` that exists per `TextField` when the text is edited.

The following code shows, what I've tried so far:

```
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - Model

class Data: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var items: [Item] = [Item(), Item(), Item()]
}

struct Item: Identifiable
{
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
}

// MARK: - View

struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var data: Data
    @State var isEditingName: Bool = false

    private var gridItems: [GridItem] { Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: data.items.count) }
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
            ForEach($data.items) { $item in
                VStack {
                    TextField("Name", text: $item.name ) { isEditing in
                        isEditingName = isEditing
                    }
                        .background(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.1))
                    Button("Doit") {
                        print("button touched for item \(item.name)")
                    }
                    .disabled(isEditingName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - App

@main
struct SwiftUI_TestApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView(data: Data())
        }
    }
}
```

Here, however, logically all buttons are deactivated and not only the one whose TextField is being edited.

Is there a simple solution to this problem? One possibility would be to store the status in a dictionary, but that seems a bit over engineered to me:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var data: Data
    @State var isEditingName = [Item:Bool]()

    private var gridItems: [GridItem] { Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: data.items.count) }
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
            ForEach($data.items) { $item in
                VStack {
                    TextField("Name", text: $item.name ) { isEditing in
                        isEditingName[item] = isEditing
                    }
                        .background(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.1))
                    Button("Doit") {
                        print("button touched for item \(item.name)")
                    }
                    .disabled(isEditingName[item] ?? false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `VStack` and content within its own `View` that receives the `$item` as a parameter

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var data: Data = Data()
    
    private var gridItems: [GridItem] { Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: data.items.count) }
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
            ForEach($data.items) { $item in
                DoItView(item: $item)
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DoItView: View {
    @State var isEditingName: Bool = false
    @Binding var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Name", text: $item.name ) { isEditing in
                isEditingName = isEditing
            }
            .background(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.1))
            Button("Doit") {
                print("button touched for item \(item.name)")
            }
            .disabled(isEditingName)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I could have come up with that idea myself. :-) Thank you.